# Variable unit width columns in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a dataset consisting of an array of arrays like this [[Point, Stack_Size, Width],....], so for example in this [5,4,6] I want to create a column with the rightmost border starting in the point 5 of the x axis, with stack of units 4 and with a width of 6 units.

Since I am new to highcharts, I am not entirely sure how to do such a thing

Comment: You could use the `Highcharts pointWidth` parameter within your `series` data. See --> http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth and http://codepen.io/dancek/pen/Jztkm for a simple example.

Comment: Weird, when drawing my chart the widths are not changing. Also is there any way of setting my width not bases on pixels but based on the x axis points? Because I want to draw my chart to be drawn from point X to point Y in termos of width.

Comment: I can't think of any built in functionality that might do this. I think one potential way might be to create an array of `x,y` values that are `point, stack_size` which will be your `series:` data and then have an array of `width` values that you assign to `pointWidth:`. You may be able to achieve the desired result if you set the `tickLength` to 1 so that each tick is one pixel?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am looking at this wrong. What I want to do, is histogram in which each column represents a numeric interval[ex: 1-7, these intervals are dynamically generated] and I want the column width of the columns to be proportional to the interval size in them, any ideas?

Comment: Calculate the interval size (i.e. 1-7 would have interval size of 7) and then set that to `pointWidth`? For example of histogram see here --> http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/column-chart

Comment: You cannot set different pointWidth for each column, only per series.